# Svelte Import Files other than JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, svelte

In the svelte example app there are imports like this:

```
import './app.css'
import svelteLogo from './assets/svelte.svg'
```

I could not find an explanation on the official documentation.

I am guessing that this is a svelte and not a js feature?

Which files can you import? And how do they get imported, e.g. `import './app.css'` applies the stylesheet and `import svelteLogo from './assets/svelte.svg'` appears to save the path in svelteLogo.

I searched "Svelte Import Files other than JavaScript", "js import files" and searched on https://svelte.dev/docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Svelte or JS, it's something build tools provide.
Common types may be supported out of the box while others require plugins/loaders.

SvelteKit e.g. uses [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) but there are others like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/).